# Create variable only once inside a looped function

Tags: python

I have function which gets looped very often.
Inside of it I want to create a variable which then will be increased constantly.
My problem is that when I define it inside the function, it gets overwritten with a new iteration, nullifying its use.

So I want to define it only once no matter how often it gets looped. But maybe there is another solution, too.

My code and the variable I mean is `aniTimer`:

```
def animate(self, sprite_array, animation_length_in_s, pos):
    aniTimer = ?    #How do I define it only once?
    ani_len     = animation_length_in_s
    sprite_len  = len(sprite_array) -1

    if time.time() >= aniTimer + ani_len:
        self.aniCount += 1
        aniTimer = time.time()
        if self.aniCount > sprite_len:
            self.aniCount = 0
```

I tried this:

```
def animate(self, sprite_array, animation_length_in_s, pos):
    try:
        aniTimer
    except NameError:
        aniTime = time.time()

    ani_len     = animation_length_in_s
    sprite_len  = len(sprite_array) -1

    if time.time() >= aniTimer + ani_len:
        self.aniCount += 1
        aniTimer = time.time()
        if self.aniCount > sprite_len:
            self.aniCount = 0
```

And I tried this:

```
def animate(self, sprite_array, animation_length_in_s, pos):
    
    if "aniTimer" not in locals():
         aniTime = time.time()

    ani_len     = animation_length_in_s
    sprite_len  = len(sprite_array) -1

    if time.time() >= aniTimer + ani_len:
        self.aniCount += 1
        aniTimer = time.time()
        if self.aniCount > sprite_len:
            self.aniCount = 0
```

But both tries always execute. Which also leads me to the questions why this happens. The `NameError` should only be there once and after defining the variable, it should be in `locals()`.

Also defining the variable globally leads to the error that the local variable gets referenced before it gets defined.
And defining it as a global var inside the functions utillity.

**MRE**

And here is a **MRE**, with nearly the same problem, but with the variabel `timer`. This function would be called by many objects, so timer would need to have a individual value for each object who called it.

```
timer = 0
breaks = 3
looping = True

def test():
    
    while looping:
        timer += 1
        print(timer)
        if timer >= breaks:
            print("Print this")
            break

test()
```

Comment: You aren't making much sense here.  If you  still have local variable, then you did *not* define it as global.  You say you want to define it only once, yet you've put that definition inside a loop.  You don't want to make it a function parameter, although that is the proper way to handle the situation.  Since you decided not to provide a calling function, you've pretty much left us guessing just what you think that the language is supposed to do for you.

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on classes that includes the concept of a "class variable".  It seems that this is what you may need.

Comment: Most of all, provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted code is never called.

Comment: @Prune added a MRE

Comment: This is not an MRE for the problem you describe.  First, you've altered the original problem description -- which is good in the long run, but it invalidates the posted solutions.  The item you label as an `MRE` says that you want a different `timer` for each object, but that would simply be an instance attribute (variable).  Since you have no declared class, you have no objects trying to call `test`.  You need to implement those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a class variable that's initialized to `None`.  This is the standard idiom in Python, with direct cognates in many other languages.

import time

```
class Foo():

    aniTime = None

    def animate(self):
        if Foo.aniTime is None:
            Foo.aniTime = time.time()

food = Foo()
food.animate()
print(food.aniTime)
time.sleep(2)
 
fool = Foo()
fool.animate()
print(fool.aniTime)
```

Output:

```
1603149209.5965674
1603149209.5965674
```

The second call does not change the originally-saved time.

Comment: For some reason my created class variable does not update after the if comparison. I am tinkering around with it a bit more.

Comment: Okay, this is not what I am searching for. The aniTimer variable needs to update with every iteration

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a global variable, you could use `global aniTime` at the top of your function to use it in your function

The best practice is probably to save your variable outside the loop where the function is being called, and you can pass it as a parameter into the function

Comment: I do not want to make it global, since other object will need to use it simultaneously.
And only defining it outside does not work, because Python will give an assignment error, since I define it in my code after comparing it to another variable.

Comment: Why not make aniTimer an attribute of your class?

Comment: This doesn't make sense: if another object has to use it, then it *needs* to be global.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel because when I want to animate multiple things inside the object of the class with different starts and lengths this solution would not work.

Comment: @Prune No, this is actually a method. And even if it would be a function, it would still be function specific.
Ofc, making a global variable would solve it, **if** it would not get overriden inside the code. While declaring it global would render the function useless for other objects to use it, since they have different animation lenghts and starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the variable outside of any functions, call it into the function and then return it from the function after each use.

```
var = 1

def example(var):
    #insert program code
    var += 1
    return var

var = example(var)
```

This will make it that every time the 'example' function runs, 'var' is passed into it and then brought back out increased by one. Every time this function is used while the program is running, the variable 'var' will be increased by one.

In this case you can substitute the 'var' variable I have used as an example for for 'aniTime' variable and you only have to define it once before the function and it is not overwritten with the initial starting value every time you call the function.